# Chrome Bad Font Rendering (Windows), But good with Brackets.io

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, adobe-brackets

I am using the latest Google Chrome version, with DirectWrite activated, but still the font rendering is terrible..

I thought is only about Chrome's abillity and there's nothing I cant do with it, but when I used "Brackets.io"'s Live Preview with Chrome, There was a nice, smooth rendering!

[image]

I've been alse trying to add `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` but it didn't work..

- *The font used is Open Sans Hebrew from Google fonts: [Linked here](http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/opensanshebrew.css)

Any Suggestions?

**EDIT:**
There's no diffrence between Brackets.io's code and Chrome's (css), I tried DirectWrite and `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` but no solution.

I think its about something on chrome's config, that bracket.io probably changed.

**EDIT:**
Now I'm sure its a problem about my chrome browser.
I went to another computer running the latest chrome and the rendering is good..
Is there a setting inside of chrome for it except DirectWrite?

Comment: Remember to [search before asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chrome+font). This has been asked many many times already.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans .. Why For the -1? I already searched, and all of the answers to those questions are not the answers for mine. My question was about font rendering with both chrome browsers. notice my question.

Comment: where's your mention what you already searched for, what you found, why that didn't apply, and what you've tried so far? Did you do a view-source comparison between the two? what was the difference? What was the CSS difference? Basically your question has no proof that you've done the debugging expected before posting on SO yet. I'll happily retract the -1 once all that "I've done my [searching, researching, and debugging](/help/how-to-ask), and this is what I found: ..." information's in the question.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans edited.

Comment: I don't see any new information on DOM or computed CSS differences, nor references to SO questions that are nearly identical but didn't help?

Comment: Seems like a legit question to me. I don't think it warrants a down vote. Alas, though, I don't have an answer. OTOH, would it really make a difference? Suppose Backets had done something special to the Chrome config for better font rendering (considering that Adobe's behind it, that seems plausible). You still can't expect average web users to adjust their Chrome config. I think the bottom line is that Chrome's font rendering is atrocious on Windows, and that is a well-known problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found my answer, the problem was **DirectWrite**.
The **DirectWrite** in chrome ignores **ClearType** *(Windows' Text Smoother)* So the font wont be smooth.

I Just ***disabled*** **Directwrite** and the text became smoother.